# Dynamic where clause sql loop

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

Following is the stored procedure

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_data_Dyna]
    {
        @param1 varchar(max) = null,
        @param2 varchar(max) = null,    
        @start varchar(max) = null,
        @end varchar(max) = null
    }
    AS

    SELECT * from table where 
    (@param1 IS NULL OR column1 IN (SELECT data FROM dbo.delimited_list_to_table(@param1,',')))  
AND (@param2 IS NULL OR column2 IN (SELECT data FROM dbo.delimited_list_to_table(@param2,',')))
AND ....?????
```

How this is working :

- All the parameters can be comma seperated
- @param1 value can be 'Germany' or 'Germany,USA' or null. This is working as expected.
- Same goes for @param2

I'm trying to include rest of the parameters which is expected to work as follows :

@start='0' and @end='100' : In this case, where clause will look like this

```
...AND val BETWEEN @start AND @end
```

@start='48,60' and @end='51,99' : In this case, where clause will look like this

```
...AND ((val Between 48 and 51) or (val Between 60 and 99))
```

@start='48,60,75' and @end='51,99,203' : In this case, where clause will look like this

```
...AND ((val Between 48 and 51) or (val Between 60 and 99) or (val Between 75 and 203))
```

I'm unable to include above 2nd/3rd point correctly. I tried to write it dynamically which is working for single values [Point 1], but how to write point 2/3 ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to do this ? Your query is going to be very complex

Comment: Can you recieve a loaded temporary table with all these values instead of parameters? That way it would simply be a join.

Comment: Can you include sample data and expected output test case wise? It will be helpful.

Comment: @Squirrel : I have selection of range in Code (c#). I can change how parameters are passed from Code to DB. Selections are like '48,51','60,99' etc. Any suggestions please?

Comment: As @Squirrel said before, it will be very complex, especially while `@Start` and `@End` parameters can hold multiple values. Thus you will need a DynamicSQL which I don't recommended.

Comment: Let us know the definition of `delimited_list_to_table('','')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think the best approach here would be to use temp tables or table variable. 
Lets go with temp tables.

```
create table #StartEnd (start int not null, end int not null, primary key (start,end))
```

then we insert from @start and @end into it using **dbo.delimited_list_to_table**. Now i am not sure about your implementation of it, so i will assume the values are numbered

```
insert into #StartEnd 
select starts.data, ends.data
  from dbo.delimited_list_to_table(@start,',') as starts
  join dbo.delimited_list_to_table(@end,',') as ends
    on starts.index = ends.index
```

Now we have to filter the values. Two approaches. Join or Exists condition

```
...
join #StartEnd on val between start and end
...

and exists (select 1 from #StartEnd where val between start and end)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

there you go. The comments / explainations are within the query

```
-- create a sample table
declare @tbl table
(
    val int
)

-- put in some sample data
insert into @tbl 
values (48), (60), (51), (99), (75), (203)

-- these are the input parameter
declare @start  varchar(100),
        @end    varchar(100)

-- and these are the input value
select  @start  = '48,60,75',
    @end    = '51,99,203'

-- the actual query
; with 
start_end as
(
    -- here i am using [DelimitedSplit8K][1]
    select  s = s.Item, e = e.Item
    from    dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K](@start, ',') s
            inner join dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K](@end, ',') e
            on  s.ItemNumber    = e.ItemNumber
)
select  t.val
from    @tbl t
where   exists
(
        select  *
        from    start_end x
        where   t.val   between x.s and x.e
)
```

you can get it here [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Answer (score 0):

Sample input (from our understanding, we guess the your data):

```
select 
* into ##delimit
from (
values 
 (1 ,'Ger','Ind',   100 )
,(2 ,'Ind',Null,    10  ) 
,(3 ,'Ger',Null,    24  )
,(4 ,'Ind','Ger',   54  )
,(5 ,'USA','Ind',   56  )
,(6 ,Null,'USA',    75  )-- NULL. But USA is three time came.
,(7 ,'USA','USA',   60  )-- same country with diff val.
,(8 ,'USA','USA',   80  )-- same country with diff val.
) demilit(Id,FromPr,ToPr,Val)

select * from ##delimit
```

Procedure (you just use this instead of your procedure):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_data_Dyna]
    (@param1 varchar(max) = NULL,
     @param2 varchar(max) = NULL,
     @start varchar(max) = NULL,
     @end varchar(max) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM ##delimit d
    JOIN
        (  --|  Here we check the val btw @start and @end       
         SELECT DISTINCT
             s.FinalColumn StartVal,        --|
             e.FinalColumn EndVal           --|
         FROM
             dbo.WithoutDelimit (@start, ',') s     --| S means 'Start' 
         JOIN
             (SELECT * 
              FROM dbo.WithoutDelimit (@end, ',')) e ON s.id = e.id --| E means 'End'
        ) se                                    --| se mean StartEnd
             ON d.val BETWEEN se.StartVal AND se.EndVal     --| Here YOUR CONDITION is accomplished 
    WHERE
         (  -- | checks whether 
          frompr IN    -- | column1 in @param1 or not
                 (SELECT FinalColumn FROM dbo.WithoutDelimit (@param1,',')  -- | frompr means, 'column1'
         ) OR @param1 is NULL       -- |
         )
 and (                                                      -- | checks whether 
  ToPr in (                                                 -- | column2 in @param2 or not
   select FinalColumn from dbo.WithoutDelimit (@param2,',') -- | frompr means, 'column2'    
  ) or @param2 is null                                      -- |
 )
end
```

Call stored procedure:

```
[get_data_Dyna] null,'usa','75','100,' -- 6 rows
[get_data_Dyna] 'Ind,Ger',null,'1,15','20,30' --2 and 3 rows are selected.
[get_data_Dyna] 'usa','usa','50,60','55,79' 
-- 7 and 8 has same country. But due to Val, 8 has been rejected.
[get_data_Dyna] NULL,'usa','70,60','80,79' 
-- 6 and 7 and 8 has been selected. Due to val condition.
```

Function (called from the stored procedure):

```
alter function WithoutDelimit       -- We use one function for all conditions.
     (@Parameter varchar (max),
      @delimit varchar (1)) 
returns @FinalTable table (
 Id int identity (1,1)              -- Auto increment
 , FinalColumn varchar (max)        -- It returns the values as a column.
) as
begin 

;with cte as                        -- recursive cte.
(
 select convert (varchar (255), @Parameter + @delimit) con
 , convert (varchar (255), @Parameter + @delimit) want
 union all
 select convert (varchar (255), stuff (con, 1, CHARINDEX (@demilit,con),'') )
 , substring (con, 1, CHARINDEX (@delimit, con) - 1)
 from cte 
 where con <> ''
) insert into @FinalTable (FinalColumn)
select want  from cte
where con <> want

 return
end
```

Revert us, if query need update.